# Accidently deleted wp-admin/index.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I accidently deleted wp-admin/index.php file, but when I uploaded the file again (index.php) it's producing an error.

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/kiddyfan/public_html/huatsms.com/wp-admin/admin.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/kiddyfan/public_html/huatsms.com/wp-admin/index.php
>   on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '/home/kiddyfan/public_html/huatsms.com/wp-admin/admin.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/kiddyfan/public_html/huatsms.com/wp-admin/index.php on line 10

What should I do? Could it be a permission setting?

Comment: Are you sure that you only have deleted the `index.php`? It looks like that's missing the file `admin.php`

Comment: What system are you using? you might be in luck if its linux

Comment: It looks like you've either deleted `admin.php` or wiped out multiple files. I'd suggest replacing the entire core to avoid any confusion over what may be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a core file, you can get it again from the WordPress repository.

Download the version of WordPress you're using from the [Release Archive](http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/).

Then overwrite your current `wp-admin` folder with the contents of the zip file you've downloaded. Or just your `admin.php` file.

Comment: Thanks All, issue resolved by replacing the (admin.php)